# Installing hosts on hadoop Ambari on centos 6

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I have configured 3 vm's to communicate with each other and i can ssh between.
I want to add them as host nodes through Ambari, but i'm getting the following error.

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>   lost connection
>   scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/common_functions
>   host=hadoop-1.frostie.com, exitcode=1
>   ERROR: Bootstrap of host hadoop-1.frostie.com fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (1)
>   ERROR MESSAGE: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>   lost connection
>   STDOUT: 
>   Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>   lost connection

I was wondering has anyone encountered this error, and would have a solution. 
Many thanks 
Frostie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own problem

when coping in the ssh passkey

you need to add the open and close

**-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**

```
###############################################################
################################################################
################################################################
################################################################
################################################################
################################################################
```

**-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----**